# Ruby - Create Google Slideshow

Tags: ruby, rubygems

Is there a Ruby gem which can be used to create a Google Slideshow / Powerpoint using plain text? I've searched all over and can't find anything I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't been able to find any that exports to Google or PowerPoint, but you might try [ShowOff](https://github.com/schacon/showoff).